# How to check if the parent element of an element is in itself the last child with javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I check if the parent, with a certain data attribute, of the element I'm clicking is a 'last child' itself? Basically, bearing in mind that they gonna be generated, most of the `<tbody>`'s have a data attribute - `data-state="closed"` - and I wanna check if one of them is the last one when I click on a child element, which is a link, that's inside it.

JS/jquery:

```
$('body').delegate('a[data-view="showhide"]', 'click', function (e) {
     var thisElem = $(this),
         thisTbody = thisElem.closest('tbody');

     e.preventDefault();

     //check to see if this element's parent is a last child
     if (thisTbody.filter('[data-state]').is(':last')) {
        console.log('this is the last tbody of its kind called \'data-state\'');
        //...Do something
     }
});
```

HTML:

```
<table>
  <tbody data-state="closed">
    <tr><td><a href="#" data-view="showhide">cell 1</a></td></tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody data-state="closed">
    <tr><td><a href="#" data-view="showhide">cell 2</a></td></tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody data-state="closed">
    <tr><td><a href="#" data-view="showhide">cell 3</a></td></tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>cell not important</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd probably use [`nextAll`](http://api.jquery.com/nextAll/):

```
if (!thisTbody.nextAll('tbody[data-state]')[0]) {
    // It's the last `tbody` with a `data-state` attribute in its
    // enclosing table
}
```

Or if you *know* that all of the `tbody` elements that have a `data-state` attribute are next to each other (e.g., that last one that doesn't have one is *always* at the end), you could just use `next('tbody[data-state]')` rather than `nextAll('tbody[data-state]')`. But it doesn't really buy you much, and it adds the assumption.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the number of `tbody` elements that have the `data-attribute` and then check the index of the current `tbody` element:

```
$(document).delegate('a[data-view="showhide"]', 'click', function (e) {
     var thisElem = $(this),
         thisTbody = thisElem.closest('tbody[data-state]'),
         thisIndex = thisTbody.index(),//get the index of the currently selected `tbody` element
         thisCount = thisElem.closest('table').find('tbody[data-state]').length;//get the number of `tbody` elements with the `data-state` attribute

     e.preventDefault();

     //see if the current index is equal to the total number of `tbody[data-state]` elements (remember that `.length` starts at one)
     if (thisIndex == (thisCount - 1)) { /*It has been found that this is the last element*/ }
});
```

Docs for `.index()`: http://api.jquery.com/index

On a side-note, your code will perform faster if you use classes instead of data-attributes:

HTML--

```
<table>
  <tbody class="closed">
    <tr><td><a href="#" class="showhide">cell 1</a></td></tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody class="closed">
    <tr><td><a href="#" class="showhide">cell 2</a></td></tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody class="closed">
    <tr><td><a href="#" class="showhide">cell 3</a></td></tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>cell not important</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

JS--

```
$(document).delegate('a.showhide', 'click', function (e) {
     var thisElem = $(this),
         thisTbody = thisElem.closest('tbody.closed'),
         thisIndex = thisTbody.index(),
         thisCount = thisElem.closest('table').find('tbody.closed');

     e.preventDefault();

     //check to see if this element's parent is a last child
     if (thisIndex == (thisCount - 1)) { /*It has been found that this is the last element*/ }
});
```

If you use classes then you can take advantage of `getElementByClass()` which is much faster than searching by `attributes` (which require looking through every DOM node in the scope of the search).